# Why --watch Jade option does not work?

Tags: html, node.js, pug

I am starting with Jade, and i have this simple file that i want to automatically re-render,

```
doctype html
html 
  head
    title Angular App CS

    link(rel='stylesheet' href='http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    script(src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular.min.js')
    script(src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js')
```

i'm using this command `jade -w -P index.jade` but only renders the first time, when i make an update to `.jade`, this following error appears:

```
TypeError: path must be a string
  at Object.fs.lstat (fs.js:675:11)
  at renderFile (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/bin/jade.js:172:6)
  at StatWatcher.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/bin/jade.js:119:11)
  at StatWatcher.emit (events.js:98:17)
  at StatWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1115:10)
```

What can be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a bug.

See [This Link](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/commit/0266982ddd9b97abe3bd31c5b55e49fc07cc3ac5#diff-f8256fead0be9dc1e7819474354a14ccR117)

Downgrade to jade 1.8.1 (`npm install jade@1.8.1 -g`) and you should be fine until the bug is fixed.